# Stretch sigmoid along horizontal x-interval

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I stretch my sigmoid function so that its tails travel with the x-interval?

For example, I want to have sigmoid be 0.001 or less at $x_0=0$ and be $0.999$ or greater at $x_1=4$.

Later I would like to change $x_1$ to be, say 32, and the sigmoid should stretch accordingly, so that it remains 0.001 or less at $x_0=0$ and at $x_1=32$ it remains $0.999$ or greater.

Also, $x_0$ is always $0$, and $x_1$ will never be negative

This formula works for my interval $[0,4]$ but fails completely for $[0, 32]$ or others.

[image]

Comment: Try $\frac1{1+k e^{-r x}}$ with $k, r$ positive and large enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sigma=\frac{1}{1+e^{-g}}$$
where
$$g=\frac{r(2x-N)}{N}$$
where
$$r=8$$

and N is the maximum value of the x-interval. For example $32$ in [0, 32]